# Regex how to identify length of numbers

Tags: regex

lets say i have  String which starts with two letters and letters are followed with underscore and numbers

```
XX_333-335                  [A-Za-z]{2}_\d{3}-\d{3}`
```

`    - this works good for me

but string can be: (this works as well)

```
XX_333-335;338;340-341        -^[A-Za-z]{2}_\d{3}-\d{3};|\d{3}|\d{3}-\d{3}
```

but how to check with regex if  number length is 3 places?

`XX_0333-0335;0338;340-0341`        -  In this example there should be no matches, because numbers have four positions not three

Is there any way how to solve it with regex?

thank you

Comment: Maybe `^[A-Za-z]{2}_\d{3}-\d{3};\d{3};\d{3}-\d{3}(?!\d)`? What is the exact string format?

Comment: ( [A-Za-z]{2}_\d{3}-\d{3})$1$1$1 ?

Comment: it differs from user ...... XX_356-357; 359-362;368;369; 370-372 .... but must be 3 digits still ....  but in  any order .... so if  any number in string has 4 digits, throw no matches XX_356-357; 359-362;368;369; 370-372

Comment: Try `^[A-Za-z]{2}_\d{3}(?:-\d{3})?(?:;\s*\d{3}(?:-\d{3})?)*$`

Comment: So `XX_45-335` should pass or fail?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  - thank you, your code snippet works really good.  Will you write it as answer, so i can accept it? thanks

Comment: Maybe `^[A-Za-z]{2}_(\d{3}(-\d{3})?)(;(?1))*$` works too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
^[A-Za-z]{2}_\d{3}(?:-\d{3})?(?:;\s*\d{3}(?:-\d{3})?)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q6E2PS/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z]{2}` - two ASCII letters
- `_` - an underscore
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `(?:-\d{3})?` - an optional occurrence of `-` and three digits
- `(?:;\s*\d{3}(?:-\d{3})?)*` - zero or more occurrences of a semi-colon followed with 0+ whitespaces, three digits and an optional sequence of three digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
^[A-Za-z]{2}_(?:\d{3}(?:[; -]+|$))+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/4ULAql/1